# Design advice for permissions checking

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, permissions, social-networking, mediator

**NOTE: This is a design question. Please let me know if stackoverflow isn't the best spot for this type of question. There may be other meta sites that am not aware of.**

I've developed a RESTful API using asp.net web API and used [mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/) as my main library for handling queries/commands. My data store is MS SQL Server.

The main purpose of this API is to serve a web app that resembles a social network: users have ***followers***, may ***like*** and ***comment*** on posts, ***upload*** and ***download*** stuff. They may also ***share*** stuff with ***everyone*** or with their ***followers*** only.

Security is obviously one of the main concerns of this app. Users can only take actions (like, comment, download, etc) if they have the appropriate permissions which are checked using complex queries (joins, subqueries, etc) at the moment.

I have thought about two options and am currently using the first one:

1. Execute a SQL query which contains all joins and checks. This gives you the benefit of a single DB round trip. However, your security check (rules) are embedded on your DB and I don't quite like that.
2. Leverage the mediator [pipeline of activities](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/09/09/tackling-cross-cutting-concerns-with-a-mediator-pipeline/) to check on permissions. This might involve a lot of DB queries (expensive), however, your code is totally object oriented and easy to understand and more importantly easy to test!

I am finding very difficult to maintain this code as those queries are everywhere and I can't easily test it. Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Regarding option #1, are those all ad-hoc queries?  If not, can you isolate the t-sql for security into stored procs (or other SQL objects)?  Would that benefit your design and/or testing efforts?

Comment: Yeah thought of a user function. That would be an improvement to option 1.